# C# - Error when trying to run my application on the emulator in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have an application that built fine without any errors. But when I am trying to run that on the emulator, I am getting the following errors which are preventing it from launching.

```
1>emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
1>Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
1>CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine
```

I am on Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on Windows 7.

Can someone please point me to what I am missing here?

Comment: do you have Intel HAXM installed and enabled?

Comment: I think you shouldn't be using VS 2015 on Windows 7!

Comment: Whats your cpu? Intel HAXM is not supported by all cpu's